# java regex find but not include in group

Tags: java, regex

Consider this simple example:

```
String myPattern= "\\[(\"(.+[^\"])\",\\s*){1,3}(\"(.+[^\"])\")\\]";
final Pattern compile1 = Pattern.compile(myPattern);
final Matcher matcher = compile1.matcher(myString);
```

I have two groups in matcher for this "`((.+[^\"])\",\s*){1,3}`":

```
((.+[^\"])\",\s*)
```

and

```
(.+[^\"])
```

But I want only one group - `(.+[^\"])`. How do I enclose in brackets the expression for {1,3} to evaluate so that it is not included into groups?
I tried using square brackets, but it did not work. I am really fed up with this issue and finally decided to ask, since I often have to do

`matcher.getGroup(1); 
matcher.getGroup(3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use non-capturing group `(?: )` i.e `(?:yourregex)`

It means match but dont include in capture group.

Comment: The name for that is "non-capturing group" ;)